# How do you disable this sample program in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

How do you make it so that you don't get this every time you make a new project in PyCharm?

[image: the sample program i was talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creation of the sample welcome script can be disabled in the `File` `>` `New Project` dialogue by unchecking the option `Create a main.py welcome script` with the subtitle *"Create a Python script that provides an entry point to coding in PyCharm"*. See the documentation [Creating a Python project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html#creating-simple-project). As shown in the screenshot.

[image]